# Luggage storage in LAX

Tags: luggage, los-angeles, lax, los

I'm traveling to LA for the day and want to do some sightseeing before taking a cruise.  What can I do with my luggage?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As a reminder, Stack Exchange expects questions to demonstrate some initial research efforts, even something as simple as a web search for "luggage storage Los Angeles." I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment points out, a search returns myriad options such as:

- [BAGBNB](https://bagbnb.com/luggage-storage/los-angeles?)
- [LAX24/7 Locker Rentals](http://www.lax247lockerrentals.com/)
- [LAX Luggage Storage](http://www.laxluggagestorage.com/)

You may also want to check for other options at the cruise port or with the cruise company, itself. If you're arriving by air, some cruise companies offer luggage transfer directly from airport to ship.

Answer (score 0):

We used LAX 24/7 Locker Rental to store our luggages. It was a very pleasant experience.  Reasonable prices and secured location. Very close to Los Angeles International Airport.